# how to connect to mongodb by using spring / paulo.mongohq.com

Tags: spring, mongodb, maven

I am trying to connect to MongoDB(paulo.mongohq.com) at Spring / Magen framework. Unfortunately, it gives

```
 java.io.IOException: couldn't connect to [paulo.mongohq.com/54.226.71.234:10045]
 bc:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out" error.
```

I guess I am doing something wrong at spring-application-context.xml.

Could you please help me where I am doing wrong at spring-application-xml ?

spring-application-context.xml:

```
<mongo:mongo host="paulo.mongohq.com" port="10045"> 
    <mongo:options
         connections-per-host="5"            
         connect-timeout="30000"
         max-wait-time="10000"           
         write-number="1"
         write-timeout="0"
         write-fsync="true"/>
</mongo:mongo>



<mongo:db-factory dbname="altayhan" mongo-ref="mongo"/>

<mongo:repositories base-package="com.borislam.repository" />

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="mongo"/>
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="altayhan"/>
 </bean>
```

Comment: mongo uses 27017 port by default.Did you change the port to 10045?

Comment: can you connect with the mongoclient ?

Comment: parvin yep tried with 27017 but could not connect. Here is the error message : java.io.IOException: couldn't connect to [paulo.mongohq.com/54.226.71.234:27017] bc:java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

Comment: Frederic i will try to connect with mongoclient.